# Why isn't $dydx$ equal to $r\cos^2\theta dr\,d\theta$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

$y = r\sin(\theta)$, $x = r\cos\theta$

$$dy = r\cos\theta d\theta$$

$$dx = \cos \theta dr$$

$$dydx = r\cos^2\theta dr d\theta$$

What did I do wrong? Also I don't know how to format sorry

Comment: Why in your approach for $dy$ is there only a $d\theta$? Shouldn't a small change in $r$ ($dr$) also affect $y$? Similarly for $x$, why does $dx$ only have $dr$. A small change in $\theta$ ($d\theta$) should produce a small change in $x$.

Answer (score 5):

You need to take total differentials
$$
dx=\cos\theta dr-r\sin\theta d\theta;\quad dy=\sin\theta dr+r\cos\theta d\theta
$$
and then you take their exterior product (when you write $dxdy$ what you actually mean is $dx\wedge dy$)
$$
dx\wedge dy=(\cos\theta dr-r\sin\theta d\theta)\wedge(\sin\theta dr+r\cos\theta d\theta)=r\cos^2\theta dr\wedge d\theta-r\sin^2\theta d\theta\wedge dr=
$$
$$
=r\cos^2\theta dr\wedge d\theta+r\sin^2\theta dr\wedge d\theta=rdr\wedge d\theta.
$$